# VBA Code to combine 2 chart sheets into one

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I currently have a macro that will plot two separate graphs in two different chart sheets. However, I am required to have them on the same chart sheet, with one directly under the other, for easy comparison purposes.

I have tried recording a macro to move the graphs as an object in a new chart sheet that I have created, but the error comes up.

Below is the recorded macro code:

```
Sheets("Graph 1").Select
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:= _
    "Combined Graphs"
Sheets("Graph 2").Select
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:= _
    "Combined Graphs"
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
```

I have also tried plotting both of them in the same sheet from the beginning, instead of trying to combine the two graphs after plotting them separately, but I am not sure how to implement this into my code that I have already -

```
Dim chtChart As Chart
Set chtChart = Chart.Add
With chtChart
.Name = "Graph 1"
.ChartType = xlLine
.SetSourceData Source:=DateRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the `Chart.Location` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196573.aspx), as hinted to in your recorded macro?

Comment: @vacip When I run the recorded macro, 'The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type' error comes up and highlights the 2nd line of code yellow. It pastes the chart picture in the new chart sheet, but not the second chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy both graphs as separate objects to a separate sheet.
Group (combine) them into a single graph
Move combined graph to desired sheet